# Objective C @property for to-many relationships

Tags: objective-c, collections, properties

I've had various cases where an Objective-C class has a property that needs to be a collection class (NSArray usually).  Is there a standard way to implement this?  It would be great to be able to just use @synthesize to set this up.  I could just declare the property as NSMutableArray and @synthesize that, but that doesn't allow me to enforce what types of objects can be placed into the collection, nor does it prevent the client code from modifying the array.  What I typically do is something like this:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *widgets;

- (void)addWidget:(Widget*)widget;
- (void)removeWidget:(Widget*)widget;
...
```

The collection is implemented as an NSMutableArray, with an NSArray containing the current contents passed back to the caller.  This seems like a lot of coding for what must be a common scenario.  Even more coding needs to be done in order to set up key-value observing.

Am I missing something, or is it really this much to work to set up a collection property?

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent client code from modifying your array by declaring the property as an NSArray, but using an NSMutableArray as the storage mechanism. The @property and @synthesize directives will still work.

There isn't really a good way to ensure type-safety of the objects returned by your array, but Objective-C programmers almost never worry about that. Its just not a common concern. If you really want to ensure that only objects of a certain type go into and come out of your array, you're going to have to write a wrapper class for NSArray to do so.

Comment: With the approach you describe, I'll still need to write the add/remove methods, so I guess I can enforce the type there.  I'll have to test to see whether that will take care of KVO compliance.  I'm hoping that it will because I'm now manipulating the the property's storage variable directly rather than handling the separate mutable collection myself.

Comment: I'm also noticing that declaring the property as an NSArray doesn't actually prevent the client code from modifying the array, because the object returned actually is an NSMutableArray.  It only causes compiler warnings.

Comment: Correct, when you declare the property to be of type NSArray, the synthesized accessor method still just returns a retain-auroreleased instance of your internal NSMutableArray object.  Users of your API shouldn't try to cast that object to NSMutableArray, since the API only promises an NSArray.  However, if you're writing a widely-used public API that can be hard to enforce.  In that case, you can still use the @synthesize directive, but implement the getter method such that it returns an autoreleased copy of your ivar, e.g. `return [[_myMutableArray copy] autorelease];`

Comment: As for ensuring KVO compliance, I don't have a lot of guidance for you there. I know that manipulating the internal storage variable directly will result in no KVO notifications, though, so you'll probably want to write yourself an internal method for adding and removing objects that are KVO-compliant.

Comment: Is returning an autoreleased copy better than returned an autoreleased NSArray?  `return [[[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfArray:widgets] autorelease];`  Maybe copy is faster?  Copy doesn't make the client's object immutable, but seeing as it is a new object it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Technically the same, but -copy is semantically preferred.  Copy does actually return a non-mutable NSArray.  To get a mutable copy of your NSMutableArray you would call -mutableCopy.

Comment: I found this documentation on making my collection property KVO-compliant:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-178830-BAJEDEFB

Implementing those methods makes my collection property KVO-compliant, as long as I only modify the contents via one of the documented methods or by calling methods on a proxy object returned by `mutableArrayValueForKey:`.  Again, it feels like a lot of boilerplate code.  I wish there was something like `@synthesize` for this.

Comment: Further investigation shows that I can skip implementing those methods as long as I only modify the contents of the widgets array via a proxy object returned by `mutableArrayValueForKey:`.  The documentation lists some advantages to implementing the collection accessor methods, however.  And if those methods are there, I can use them directly to modify the property in a KVO-compliant way.

Interestingly, the presence of the `mutableArrayValueForKey:` method seems to make it impossible to make the property truly read-only.

Comment: Hey @brentopolis, if this answer makes sense to you, please mark it as accepted, so that people know the question has been answered.